# Which method is suitable for this scenario in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, multidimensional-array, selenium-webdriver

Currently working on **Selenium WebDriver** and code had been written in **Java**.

The Scenario is If i select the drop down value = Month range or Date Range or Week Range then the related drop down will populate (i.e if month Range is selected the From month and To month will be populated, if Date Range is selected the From Date and To Date will be populated, if Week Range is selected the From week and To week will be  populated).

What Exactly i want to check whether if the Month Range drop down value is selected in the Period drop down then verify the related drop down that is From month and To month is populating.

Please anyone can help me for this secnario.
The HTML for Period:

```
<select id="periodId" name="period" style="display: none;">
<option value="l4w">Last 4 Weeks</option>
<option value="l52w">Last 52 Weeks</option>
<option value="daterange">Date Range</option>
<option value="weekrange">Week Range</option>
<option selected="" value="monthrange">Month Range</option>
<option value="yeartodate">Year To Date</option>
</select>
```

Once the week range is selected it need to select the below The HTML for WeekRange:

```
<dt id="week-label">
<dd id="week-element">
<select id="fromWeekYear" style="width:60px" name="fromWeekYear">
<option value="2010"> 2010</option>
<option value="2011"> 2011</option>
<option value="2012"> 2012</option>
<option value="2013"> 2013</option>
<option selected="" value="2014"> 2014</option>
</select>
<select id="fromWeek" style="width:60px" name="fromWeek">
<option value="1"> W 1</option>
<option value="2"> W 2</option>
<option value="3"> W 3</option>
<option value="4"> W 4</option>
<option value="5"> W 5</option>
<option value="6"> W 6</option>
<option value="7"> W 7</option>
<option value="8"> W 8</option>
<option value="9"> W 9</option>
<option selected="" value="10"> W 10</option>
<option value="11"> W 11</option>
<option value="12"> W 12</option>
<option value="13"> W 13</option>
<option value="14"> W 14</option>
<option value="15"> W 15</option>
<option value="16"> W 16</option>
<option value="17"> W 17</option>
<option value="18"> W 18</option>
<option value="19"> W 19</option>
<option value="20"> W 20</option>
<option value="21"> W 21</option>
<option value="22"> W 22</option>
<option value="23"> W 23</option>
<option value="24"> W 24</option>
<option value="25"> W 25</option>
<option value="26"> W 26</option>
<option value="27"> W 27</option>
<option value="28"> W 28</option>
<option value="29"> W 29</option>
<option value="30"> W 30</option>
<option value="31"> W 31</option>
<option value="32"> W 32</option>
<option value="33"> W 33</option>
<option value="34"> W 34</option>
<option value="35"> W 35</option>
<option value="36"> W 36</option>
<option value="37"> W 37</option>
<option value="38"> W 38</option>
<option value="39"> W 39</option>
<option value="40"> W 40</option>
<option value="41"> W 41</option>
<option value="42"> W 42</option>
<option value="43"> W 43</option>
<option value="44"> W 44</option>
<option value="45"> W 45</option>
<option value="46"> W 46</option>
<option value="47"> W 47</option>
<option value="48"> W 48</option>
<option value="49"> W 49</option>
<option value="50"> W 50</option>
<option value="51"> W 51</option>
<option value="52"> W 52</option>
<option value="53"> W 53</option>
</select>
</dd>
<dd> </dd>
<dd> </dd>
```

[image: 1st Filter Section]

Based on the Selection of the 1st filter option(i.e. WeekRange) 2nd filter (From Week to To Week is appearing as follows:

[image: 2nd Filter Section]

Comment: Could anyone please help me for this secnario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In javascript you have to write like below code.

var type = $("#periodId").val();

if(type == "weekrange"){

// then put java script to hide the related element/select boxes.

}else if(){

// then put java script to hide the related element/select boxes.

}else{

 // then put java script to hide the related element/select boxes.

}
```